# How to switch django database before I login in admin?

Tags: django, database, switch-statement

I face a problem that I design a information system base on django-admin.

But I have several independent system to build.every system's Features are all the same.

So I want to put a texbox to select to switch my database before I login in admin.How can I do that?
for example ,when I want to login in admin,I want to freely switch from db1 to db2 or reverse.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db1.sqlite3'),
    },
   'newData': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db2.sqlite3'),
    }


}
```

Comment: You want textbox with database select option or after login into admin there you can change db ? which one is it ?

Comment: Hello @rajasimon,I want the former: textbox with database select option Before I login in.

Comment: hello,whos I can help me to work out this?